# Can't connect to Meteor with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor, pymongo

I am trying to connect to a Meteor Mongo database through pymongo. Here's the code:

```
def get_mongo_url(site):
  # return "mongodb://client-xxxxx:yyyyy@production-db-c1.meteor.io:27017/site"
  import subprocess
  p = subprocess.Popen(['meteor', 'mongo', '--url', site], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = p.communicate()
  print out
  return out

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(get_mongo_url("mysite.com"))
```

And the error (the print statement yields a correct url)

```
>> mongodb://client-xxxxx:yyyyy@production-db-c1.meteor.io:27017/site
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "private/test.py", line 46, in <module>
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(get_mongo_url(METEOR_SITE))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 369, in __init__
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'client-xxxxx'), ('nonce', u'zzzzz'), ('key', u'ttttt')]) failed: auth fails
```

If I run `meteor mongo --url mysite.com`, copy the result into the `return ...` at the top of the function and uncomment it, the connection works. Why can't I connect programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subprocess code appends a line feed character `\n` to the end of the url.

You need to strip that with `.rstrip()`

The right way to do that is to replace the return in your function with

`return out.rstrip()`

For confirmation purposes I will show what happens with the function as-is and 
rstrip() applied/unapplied to the return.

> > > murl = get_mongo_url('').rstrip()
> > >       mongodb://client-faf1d0db:746d8f43-367b-dde2-b69a-039ff8b9f7fa@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/_meteor_com
> > >
> > > client = pymongo.MongoClient(murl)

Worked OK

> > > murl = get_mongo_url('')
> > >       mongodb://client-3578a20b:d4ddeec9-6d24-713e-8ddb-c357b664948a@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/_meteor_com
> > >
> > > client = pymongo.MongoClient(murl)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/action/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 383, in **init**
> > >           raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
> > >       pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'client-3578a20b'), ('nonce', u'e14e2bdb3d8484b9'), ('key', u'9
> > >       c101b78ff1a617a9c5f0def36c7e3d9')]) failed: auth fails

Failed without the rstrip.

> > > murl = get_mongo_url('')
> > >       mongodb://client-1a193a61:4c9c572e-22e3-4b7e-44a1-dc76bfb65e86@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/_meteor_com
> > >
> > > client = pymongo.MongoClient(murl)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/action/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 383, in **init**
> > >           raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
> > >       pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'client-1a193a61'), ('nonce', u'a2576142b1a33d8b'), ('key', u'4
> > >       419c490bcdcc65b20f2950c3b106d59')]) failed: auth fails

Failed again (no rsrtip)

> > > murl = get_mongo_url('').rstrip()
> > >       mongodb://client-ce463608:d7dc6be0-499f-1808-43e1-fdfb8b6e8ebc@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/_meteor_com
> > >
> > > client = pymongo.MongoClient(murl)

Worked (rstrip used).

---

The following is general info on mongodb URLs.  You may know this already.

The URL that pymongo wants is not a web URL but a URL-like specifier for a mongo database connection.
For a development environment, the mongodb is usually set up on port 3001, which is not the default mongodb port for a production server.

Meteor applications can be configured to use a mongodb hosted anywhere.  It does not have to be on the same server that serves the meteor content.  The specification of this is done through the mongodb:// URL which is what pymongo wants.  pymongo doesn't depend on the meteor website url, which can be very different from the mongodb url.

Here is some code I am using

```
import pymongo
MONGO_URL = r'mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor'
###
def connect():
  client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
  return client

def findUser(c, email):
  users = c.meteor.users
  return users.find_one({"emails.address": email})
```

According to the mongodb site on Github, The [`MONGO_URL` format](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) is

`mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

so the mongodb url   `mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor` can be interpreted like this:

```
* mongodb:// means this describes a mongodb connection
* localhost means connect locally 
* :3001 means use non-standard port number 3001.  this is how "meteor run" sets up mongo
* /meteor means connect to the database called "meteor"
```

Comment: I'm connecting to a production Meteor deployment though.

Comment: addressing the edit -- this is because Meteor usernames and passwords generated by that command only last 60 seconds. I still should be able to connect to it though..

Comment: Probably wont matter, but try putting that URL string through `.rstrip()` before you use it to get rid of the linefeed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference would be in the URL that works vs the one that does not except for the line feed.

Comment: It IS the line feeds here, if I am careful to use the url from your `get_mongo_url().rstrip()` immediately it will work. But without the rstrip() it does NOT work.